# How to pass more than 4 arguments to FakeItEasy Invokes()?

Tags: c#, fakeiteasy

I am trying to convert a helper method I wrote mocking `ILogger` using Moq to FakeItEasy.  The `Log()` method mocked in the `ILogger` requires 5 arguments.

```
Log(LogLevel, EventId, FormattedLogValues, Exception, Func<object, Exception, string>)
```

It appears that FakeItEasy has capped the number of arguments to 4. (From the [docs](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/invoking-custom-code/)):

```
// Pass up to 4 original call argument values into the method that creates the exception.
A.CallTo(()=>fakeShop.NumberOfSweetsSoldOn(A<DateTime>._))
  .Invokes((DateTime when) => System.Console.Out.WriteLine("showing sweet sales for " + when))
  .Returns(17);
```

Therefore when I write this code...

```
var logs = new List<string>();
var logger = A.Fake<ILogger<ElasticSearchRepository>>();
A.CallTo(() => logger.Log(A<LogLevel>._, A<EventId>._, A<FormattedLogValues>._, A<Exception>._, A<Func<object, Exception, string>>._))
    .Invokes((LogLevel a, EventId b, FormattedLogValues x, Exception c, Func<object, Exception, string> d) => logs.Add(x.ToString()));
```

... I get the following error

```
 Delegate 'Action<IFakeObjectCall>' does not take 5 arguments
```

Is there something I should be doing differently?  It's hard to imagine anyone arbitrarily picking 4 as the max arguments that can be passed so I'm guessing there is a reason.  Moq's `Callback()` doesn't have the same limitations.

Comment: I had a quick look at the code on github and it seems to be the case, some overloads of functions are only defined up to 4 arguments.

Comment: Not a 100% duplicate but I guess at least related: [FakeItEasy ReturnLazily with more than 4 arguments method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31018199/1220550)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It appears that FakeItEasy has capped the number of arguments to 4.

Not really. There are helper overloads for up to 4 arguments, but you can actually have any number of arguments, albeit with a less convenient syntax:

```
A.CallTo(() => logger.Log(A<LogLevel>._, A<EventId>._, A<FormattedLogValues>._, A<Exception>._, A<Func<object, Exception, string>>._))
    .Invokes(call => logs.Add(call.GetArgument<FormattedLogValues>("state").ToString()));
```